# Need v-html code to give highest value?

Tags: vue.js

Im about to do some stats on my site, where i want people to be able to see the highest amount won ever.

The line v-html="user.winnings.price"   gives me the price of the current winning. But what should i type instead to make it show highest winning?

```html
<div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center; display: block; color: black; font-weight: bold;">
    <h2>Congratulations!</h2>
    <img style="width: 180px;" :src="user.winnings.image"><br>
    <span v-html="user.winnings.name"></span><br>
    <span v-html="user.winnings.price"></span>
</div>
```

Greating me xD

Comment: That depends on your API, which is missing from the question.

Comment: `<span v-html="theHighestWinning"></span>`